# Scaling and repositioning with SVG.js difficulties

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I’m using svg.js to manipulate SVGs within the browser. Most of what I’m doing is relatively simple, but I’m having some difficulties with scaling/positioning a few objects.

I have an SVG that contains a “Pin” icon. You can click on the SVG to zoom it (which just resizes it to fill the browser viewport), in turn resizing all of its children, including the Pin. I need to scale this icon back down to its original size of `36px x 36px` and reposition it so the bottom center of the Pin sits where it originally sat. I’ve got the resizing down, but the repositioning piece escapes me.

**Some example states:**

1. Scaled at 100% with Pin at base size of `36px x 36px`.

   [image]
2. Scaled up by `9.77241379` with pin scaled down to its base size of `36px x 36px`. Using svg.js the `scale()` method scales at the center point of the pin, leaving it floating in space.

   [image]

What I’m using to scale the Pin when the parent container is scaled up:

```
scaleHotspot(hotspot) {
    const child = hotspot.first();
    const bbox = child.bbox();
    const rbox = child.rbox();
    const scale = bbox.w / rbox.w;

    hotspot.scale(scale);
}
```

Because the Pin is scaled using its center point it’s now sitting up higher than it’s supposed to be. I need to determine how much to move the Pin down to have the point of the Pin sitting in its original position.

I originally thought this worked but testing in various places yielded strange results.

```
const newY = -(bbox.height / 2 - (bbox.height - (1 / scale)));
```

Suggestions around getting the Pin positioned so that its bottom center point sits where the unscaled version was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`.transform()`](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/manipulating/#transform-as-setter), you can define a center around which to scale. Use `.bbox()` to find that point in current user space. Since these coordinates already include pre-existing transformations, set the `relative` flag to add the scaling on top:

```
scaleHotspot(hotspot) {
    const bbox = hotspot.bbox();
    const rbox = hotspot.rbox();
    const scale = bbox.w / rbox.w;
    const center = bbox.x + bbox.w / 2;
    const bottom = bbox.y + bbox.h;

    hotspot.transform({scale: scale, cx: center, cy: bottom}, true);
}
```

Comment: That’s perfect. Works wonderfully. Thanks so much! Learned a thing or two.

Comment: As an addition: what you usually want when calling rbox is `hotspot.rbox(hotspot.doc())` because you want the box to be relative to the root svg and not to the absolute 0,0 of the browser

Comment: @Fuzzyma Good point, but since the OP wanted the pin icon to retain size _on the screen_, `hotspot.rbox()` is actually the safe way to play it.

Comment: OP said, that the icon is in the svg. When the svg is moved, the icon needs to move too. And when you then use rbox without argument it will result in the wrong position. So it's always adviced to use twenty argument when you are not specifically wanting the rbox related to the window itself